# avoid implicit enum raw value conversion

Tags: swift, enums

I am attempting to avoid the implicit conversion of an enum into a string in a case like this:

```swift
enum Animal {
    case cat
}

func getTag(forAnimal animal: Animal) -> String {
    // fails with "Cannot convert value of type 'Animal' to specified type 'String' which is good!!!"
    // return animal

    // does return "cat" which I don't want developers to be able to do!!!
    return "\(animal)"
}

print(getTag(forAnimal: .cat)) // prints "cat"
```

The 2nd return works because print calls `.description` on the object.
Swift apparently adopts `CustomStringConvertible` for enums automatically and returns the case name as a `String`. Edit: Apparently , print does not call `.description`.

I thought about conforming to the protocol and alert developers (with something that throws an error perhaps).

But what I am wanting to do really is to have the enum NOT conform to said protocol, or have a compile-time error. Is this possible?

Comment: This is incorrect, `Animal` does not conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, and `print` doesn't call `description` in this case. In general, you are able to do `"\(x)"` for `x` of any type. You can stop this at runtime by conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` and `fatalError` in the `description` property, though this could be a bit confusing to users of your code.

Comment: What is being called in `"\(x)"` then?

Comment: String interpolation calls [String.init(describing:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(describing:)-67ncf) IIRC, which produces an "unspecified" result if the thing doesn't conform to any protocols. See the link for more info.

Comment: Turns out, it isn't `String.init(describing:)`, but [some internal function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/StringInterpolation.swift#L178), whose implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/85d9507fde3deb5889f71f81f09a05319898b029/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift#L403). Anyway, the result is the same as `String(describing:)` for enums not conforming to any protocols, and it is also unspecified in the documentation what the result of this string interpolation would be.

Comment: I don't understand why you want this behavior. It is such a useful feature built right into swift. There are efficient ways of hiding the value or date without crashing the system or causing a compile time error.

Comment: This is the closest to a solution so far: Somebody described the issue here
https://forums.swift.org/t/enum-case-and-string-interpolation-is-not-very-safe-can-mistakenly-interpolate-the-case-when-actually-want-case-rawvalue-is-there-anyway-to-prevent-this/56179/5

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `StringInterpolation` and implement an `appendInterpolation` method for that specific type. This way you can simply determine how your enumeration would interpolate its value. If you don't want any string to be generated you just need to create a dummy method:

```
enum Animal {
    case cat
}

extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Animal) { }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
"\(Animal.cat)"  // "" it results in an empty string
```

---

If you want a compile-time error you can add a deprecated availability warning:

[image]

```
@available(swift, deprecated: 2)
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Animal) { }
}
```

Comment: this is interesting....
Now, what I really want to do is avoid this behavior altogether: if somebody ends up using the enum as a string, have a compile-time error.

Comment: You can add something like `@available(swift, deprecated: 2)` to the extension